# Wordpress AJAX Request - ERROR 403 Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing here today because I can't figure out what is the problem with my code to delete a post on the front end of my website.

Here is the code I've implemented to make this work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.delete-listing-btn').on('click', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', favorites_data.nonce);
        },
            url: 'https://www.mallorca-select.com/wp-json/wp/v2/properties-for-sale/2303',
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: (response) =>{
                console.log("COngratus");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: (response) => {
                console.log("Fail");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I run this without the "nonce" it gives me a 401 error and when i use the nonce it gets me a 403 error. You can see it in the screenshot below.

If anyone can help me to figure out what I'm missing would be great.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get an 401 because your AJAX isn't authorized to delete Posts. Would be a big Problem, if everyone could send such Kind of AJAX-requests to your WordPress and delete all your Content.

As of the API, your JS code has to be modifyed to something like this:

```
...
//make the request
    var dataArray = {};
    var urlRequest = WP_API_Settings.root+"/posts/"+postID;
    var typeRequest = 'DELETE';

    //first set the standard stuff
    dataArray["action"] = "wp_api";
    //dataArray["_wp_json_nonce"] =  WP_API_Settings.nonce;

    //make the post
    $.ajax(urlRequest,{
        url : urlRequest,
        type : typeRequest,
        data : dataArray,
        cache : false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce);

            if (beforeSend) {
                return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    }).done(
....
```

Click [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162604/wp-api-delete-request-from-jquery-ajax)!  to see the original answer

Comment: When I use this code as you gave me it returns "(index):30651 Uncaught ReferenceError: WP_API_Settings is not defined"